# Процесс на фоне

Tags: unix, linux, perl

Инструментарий

1. kUbuntu 12.04
2. Perl

Я запускаю команду, допустим kate, терминал мне открывает окно, и пока окно не закроется терминал не доступен для новых команд (именно это окно), и если я закрою терминал, то и закроется окно.

Я же хочу, чтобы терминал не ждал, пока отработает программа, а был готов для новых команд, а программа для него работала на фоне.

То же самое с perl скриптом, я хочу, чтобы при вызове функции `system()` скрипт не ждал его завершения, а дальше пошел работать, оставив программу работать на фоне (асинхронный запрос)

Perl не знаю. На линуксе недавно, скрипт очень нужен, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sleep 60 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

И кстати. Не советую использовать kate для программирования редактирования файлов. Советую тебе посмотреть в сторону [sublime text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Comment: Спасибо, но я kate использовал для примера. А программирую я на geany

Comment: А за редактор благодарю, я пороюсь, в демо он мне понравился

Answer (score 2):

Для запуска процесса в фоновом режиме используется функция fork(), которая возвращает PID дочернего процесса. На пример:

```
use strict;
my $PID = fork();
if ( $PID > 0 ) {
    print "Родительский процесс\n";
}
else {
    printf "Дочерний процесс, работающий в фоне с PID=%d\n", $PID;      
}
```

Как правило, дальше испольщуют функцию exec()